# Where can A/C condenser be located other than in front of radiator?

Tags: ford, ac, f100

1953 F-100 w/ 428 Cobra Jet FE motor.
I want to spare my grill and avoid putting the condenser in front of the radiator. Plus, it's already a beast to cool in hot weather, and I live in hell. (It's hot here.)  Any other locations for the condenser that you can suggest? Be creative! I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with moving the AC condenser is that it won't do the job. You have to have air flow through it for it to work. Placing it anywhere besides in front of the radiator would be like not having be it at all.

My suggestion to you is to redesign the mount for you grill so you have room to mount the condenser, yet not move the grill. The condenser isn't that wide, most being no more than an inch.

If this isn't possible, see if you can mount the radiator further back so you can find room in front of it. There has to room front or rear to move the radiator.

Either way it's going to take some fabrication to make it happen, but shouldn't be impossible either way. When you are looking to put things into place where they weren't in the first place, you have to make some changes (but I guess you already realized it.)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could do what Roadkill did with their [rear-engined Mazda pickup](http://youtu.be/XuHIemMF4kY) and place it in the truck bed with some duct work (or better, auxiliary electric fans) to keep air flowing across the condenser.

The problem, as @Paulster2 highlights is that the ability of the AC system to reject heat will be impacted by how much air can flow through the condenser. This is why it is placed at the front of most vehicles; the movement of air through the condenser is a freebie whenever the car moves.

Answer (score 1):

I put mine under the truck in the frame and installed a electric fan to keep it cool